# How is Set Difference Defined for Multisets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, multisets

I'm interested in understanding the definition of set difference in multisets, but haven't been able to find a definition online.

For an example, suppose $A = \{a, b, b, c, c, c\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c\}$ are multisets. My question is, how is the set difference $A$ \ $B$ defined?

Is $A$ \ $B = \varnothing$, or the multiset $\{b, c, c\}$?

Comment: You can define it whichever way is more useful for you (or define both, and give them different names).  I'm not aware of any standard definition.

Comment: In my experience your first version is more common — probably common enough to be considered standard, though I think that it would always be best to specify what you’re using.

Comment: In multisets multiplicity is relevant. This means that $\{ a,a \} \setminus \{ a \}$ must be $\{ a \}$. Otherwise, why use multisets ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, this in fact was the reason I needed multisets to begin with. It was to solve a graph theory problem where I may have a set of non-distinct edge weights. That’s why I need a precise formalization of multiset operations, particularly the set difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, we can write these multisets as functions, such as:

$A=\{a,b,b,c,c,c\}$ becomes $m_A (x) = [a]+2[b]+3[c]$

$B=\{a,b,c\}$ becomes $m_B (x) = [a]+[b]+[c]$

The multiset difference, $m_C (x)$, is defined as $m_C(x) = \text{max} \{m_A (x) - m_B (x),0\}$

$m_C (x)=[b]+2[c]$

$A\setminus B =\{b,c,c\}$

Note there are some consequences for this deﬁnition that may not align to the laws of classical set theory. See [Singh etal (2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13370-016-0400-9) for more details.  Another reference that formalises multiset operations, such as set difference, is [Syropoulos (2001)](https://asyropoulos.eu/papers/PDF/MathMSet.pdf).